# wpf and ef select part of a table with include

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a table with many fields and I want to get only a few individual fields, I work with EF and I add another table to the query as follows

```
            var Test= ve.Folders.Include("Hosting")
                .Where(a => a.Collateral!= true)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(p => new 
                {
                    id = p.Folder_Id,
                    name = p.Full_Name,
                    add = p.Address,
                    date1 = p.Collateral_Date,
                    sName = p.Hosting._Name
                })
                .ToArray();
```

But with the field (sName=  p.Hosting._Name) that is associated with the second table without any value query not working
Many attempts have been tried but without result (interesting when I ask without Select everything works well)

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: side note, .Where(a => a.Collateral!= true) should really just be .Where(a => !a.Collateral)

Comment: try with `sName = p.Hosting!=null?p.Hosting._Name:string.Empty`

Comment: @2kay No it does not work

Comment: @Damith It works great with your answer and the other answer, thank you both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to note is that, in this case, there's little benefit to the `Select` after the call to `AsEnumerable`, since all the data in the table is still queried from the database (not just the fields you specifiy).

If you want to avoid that, and only query those five fields, you can remove the `AsEnumerable` call. That means the `Select` will execute as part of the SQL query. This also means the `Include` is unnecessary, since the `Select` will query all of the data you want.

```
var Test= ve.Folders
            .Where(a => a.Collateral!= true)
            .Select(p => new 
            {
                id = p.Folder_Id,
                name = p.Full_Name,
                add = p.Address,
                date1 = p.Collateral_Date,
                sName = p.Hosting._Name
            })
            .ToArray();
```